# Упорядочивание (кластеризация) матрицы

Tags: matlab

В ходе выполнения задания получается матрица, которую требуется упорядочить

[image]

Без специальных функций кластеризации можно визуально выделить соответствующие кластеры

[image]

однако хочется большего. При этом встроенные функции *Matlab* типа *symamd*, *symrcm*, *colamd* работают в данном случае очень плохо, и требуемая кластеризация не происходит.

Скажите, пожалуйста, если кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой, не могли бы Вы выложить соответствующую функцию или алгоритм или ссылки на литературу по этой теме?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вполне может сработать методика применяемая к анализу изображений.

Первоначально для перевода картинки в полутоновое rgb2gray, там же есть другие функции для подготовки изображения. 
Дальше сделать морфологические операции (смотрите вики и статью на хабре, много ссылок дать не могу). Например сделать морфологическое замыкание что бы закрасить внутренности кластера. И размыкание что бы убрать шум и несущественные детали. 
Потом наложить маску на исходные данные и с ними уже работать. Еще для анализа можно использовать blob analysis. 
Что то подобное в интернете: http://habrahabr.ru/post/114335/
привожу набор функций по которым стоит заглянуть в хелп матлаба:

rgb2gray
imfill
strel
imshow

Comment: Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).